git: use only UTC in logs and commits
What combination of log.date, --date=, ...-local, TZ= etc leads to the following desired outcome:

git log prints all commits, made in whatever timezone / DST, in UTC, so I can remove %z from --pretty in all my log aliases
git commit registers all commits with the real UTC timestamp (adjusting the date, not simply dropping the timezone)
preferably without setting TZ globally, which affects all glibc-linked programs (is there a GIT_TZ? I haven't found one)


I would do:
# 1. git log to print all commits in UTC:
git log --date=iso --date=local --date=format-local:"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z" --date=format:%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ

# 2. git commit to register all commits with the real UTC timestamp:
git commit --date="$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")"

# 3. to make git commands above without setting TZ globally:
env TZ=UTC git log
env TZ=UTC git commit --date="$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")"


(1) is git config log.date 'format-local:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %Z. I don't know why you're combining multiple date options. But thanks for capital %Z, I had forgotten about that. Compared to normal (strftime) %z, it doesn't print the timezone if it would be +0000

with quotes it should work: --date=format:"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"

your command (1) works as it is, I just don't know why you're combining multiple formats, which actually override each other. Furthermore, git config log.date 'format-local:...' achieves the same purpose, and affects any subsequent aliases as well.

Ah, I was wrong again. %Z (capital) only does something with format-local, otherwise it's empty
